# glob skipping files

Tags: perl, file, search, loops, glob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Perl's glob return undef for every other call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274642/why-does-perls-glob-return-undef-for-every-other-call)

This is a continuation of another problem I was having where I needed to find a file that had a long name but I knew what part of the name was, here is the code I used:

```
my @RTlayerRabcd = ("WIRA_Rabcd_RT","WIRB_Rabcd_RT","WIRC_Rabcd_RT","WIRD_Rabcd_RT","WIRE_Rabcd_RT","BASE_Rabcd_RT");

#Rabcd calculations
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) 
{
    print "@RTlayerRabcd[$i]\n";
    #Searching for Rabcd Room Temperature readings
    my $file = glob($dir . "*@RTlayerRabcd[$i]" . '.txt');
    print "$file\n";
    my $Rtot = 0;
    #Open file, Read line
    open (FILE, $file);
    while (<FILE>)
    {
        #read line and and seperate at "tab" into $temp, $Res 
        chomp;
         ($Res, $temp) = split("\t");   
        $j++;
        $Rtot=$Res+$Rtot;

     }
     close (FILE);

    $Ravg = $Rtot/$j;
    print FILE_OUT "$Ravg \t";



 }
```

After I run the code I get the following print outs:

```
WIRA_Rabcd_RT                                                               
Vesuvious_C6R8_051211/vesu_R6C8_05112011_WIRA_Rabcd_Rt.txt
WIRB_Rabcd_RT

WIRC_Rabcd_RT                                                      
Vesuvious_C6R8_051211/vesu_R6C8_05112011_WIRC_Rabcd_Rt.txt                            
WIRD_Rabcd_RT                                                

WIRE_Rabcd_RT                                                   

BASE_Rabcd_RT                                             
Vesuvious_C6R8_051211/vesu_R6C8_05112011_BASE_Rabcd_Rt.txt
```

The program seems to be skipping files, any idea why?

Comment: Use strict and warnings, use a conditional on your `open()`, then you might get some information. Obviously, the glob does not find the file. Also. `$array[0]`, not `@array[0]`, is the way to refer to an array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scalar context, [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) iterates through all files matched by the glob, returning `undef` after the last one.  It's intended to be used as the condition in a `while` loop, for example:

```
while (my $file = glob('*.c')) {
  say $file;
}
```

The iterator is tied to that particular call to `glob`.  Once the iteration has started, there's no way to reset the iterator early.  `glob` ignores its argument until after it has returned `undef`.

You can fix your problem by using `glob` in list context:

```
my ($file) = glob($dir . "*@RTlayerRabcd[$i]" . '.txt');
```

Comment: Or get a bunch of files with `glob` and use `grep` to get the right one.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the directory Vesuvious_C6R8_051211 does not contain the files *WIRB_Rabcd_RT.txt, *WIRD_Rabcd_RT.txt and *WIRE_Rabcd_RT.txt. What is the file listing of that directory? Also, I recommend you check the return code for [open()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), to be sure that it indeed opened a file successfully.

Comment: No, it's because he's calling `glob` in scalar context but not as a loop condition.